# Checkbox like radio button, limit to only one selection, uncheck if other checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, conditional-statements

The current js works fine, but at the moment it's possible to select multiple checkboxes. However, I want to limit only the selection to only one checkbox , so that checkboxes would behave like radio buttons - if one is checked the other one is unchecked, and that only one checkbox is allowed  :

JS code:

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Show/hide fields conditionally
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
(function($) {
$.fn.conditionize = function(options){ 
  
   var settings = $.extend({
      hideJS: true
  }, options );
  
  $.fn.showOrHide = function(listenTo, listenFor, $section) {
    if ($(listenTo).is('select, input[type=text]') && $(listenTo).val() == listenFor ) {
      $section.slideDown();
    }
    else if ($(listenTo + ":checked").val() == listenFor) {
      $section.slideDown();
    }
    else {
      $section.slideUp();
    }
  } 

  return this.each( function() {
    var listenTo = "[name=" + $(this).data('cond-option') + "]";
    var listenFor = $(this).data('cond-value');
    var $section = $(this);

    //Set up event listener
    $(listenTo).on('change', function() {
      $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
    });
    //If setting was chosen, hide everything first...
    if (settings.hideJS) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
    //Show based on current value on page load
    $.fn.showOrHide(listenTo, listenFor, $section);
  });
}
}(jQuery));

$('.conditional').conditionize();
```

and here is the html code:

```
<div id="demo">
  <h3>I'm interested in</h3>
  <label class="solo"><input type="radio" name="example1" value="private"><span></span>
    <span class="label-icon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Solo/Private Lessons</span>
  </label>
  <label class="group"><input type="radio" name="example1" value="group"><span></span>
    <span class="label-icon"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Group Lessons</span>
  </label>
    <label class="workshop"><input type="radio" name="example1" value="workshop"><span></span>
      <span class="label-icon"><i class="fas fa-guitar"></i> Workshops and Clinics</span>
    </label>

  <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="example1" data-cond-value="private">
    <h4>Which instruments are you interested in learning?</h4>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="guitar"><span></span> Guitar</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="drums"><span></span> Drums</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="violin"><span></span> Violin</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="example3"><span></span> Bass</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="example3"><span></span> Flute</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="example3"><span></span> Saxophone</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="example3"><span></span> Other</label>


      <div class="years-of-experience">
    <div class="conditional inline" data-cond-option="guitar" data-cond-value="on">
      <label><input type="text" size="4"> &nbsp; Years of experience in guitar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="drums" data-cond-value="on">
      <label><input type="text" size="4"> &nbsp; Years of experience in drums</label>
    </div>
    <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="violin" data-cond-value="on">
      <label><input type="text" size="4"> &nbsp; Years of experience in violin</label>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="student-profile">
        <h4>Tell us a little more about yourself:</h4>
        <!-- Name -->
        <div>
          Student name<br>
            <input type="text" value="First"> <input type="text" value="Last">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Age<br>
            <span class="explanation">Currently accepting students 5+</span>
            <input type="text"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Parent/guardian name
            <span class="explanation">If student is a minor</span>
             <input type="text" value="First"> <input type="text" value="Last">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Occupation
            <span class="explanation">If student, list school</span>
             <input type="text"></label>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.student-profile -->
      <input type="submit" class="big-blue-button" value="Let's take a look at the class contract &rarr;">
  </div><!-- .solo-classes -->

  <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="example1" data-cond-value="group">
    <p>What kind of group lessons are you interested in?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="conditional" data-cond-option="example1" data-cond-value="workshop">
    <p>What kind of workshops are you interested in?</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And what is you question?

Comment: How to limit checkbox selection only to 1 ? At the moment you can select multiple checkboxes but I want to make it so that only 1 checkbox is allowed to be selected. An d if one is selected if you select another one it would switch, just like the radio buttons

Comment: @Reporter http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/724/ this is the checkbox behaviour I'm looking for, but I don't know how to merge this js code snippet properly into the js code which I've posted

Comment: Users tend to buy in to established UI conventions, so why are you risking their confusion by using check-box, instead of radio, inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I found only the following way

First:
Add the attribute `onClick` with value `check(this)` to each of your checkboxes.

Second:
Add following jquery function to your code:

```
function check(clickedObj)
{
  //Have you clicked checkbox checked or not?
  let checkboxState =$(clickedObj).prop( "checked" );
  //Find the container div and the find all containing checkboxes
  let checkboxes = $(clickedObj).parent().parent().find("input[type='checkbox']");
  //Loop through all foundend checkboxes and uncheck all
  $(checkboxes).each(function()
  {
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
  })
  //Restore selected checkbox state in case you wanted to check it
  if (checkboxState == true) {
    $(clickedObj).prop("checked", true);
  }
}
```

According my jsfiddle it did work. Any ideas for improvements are welcome. :-)

Comment: it doesn't work for me https://codepen.io/Happster/pen/MWjdaVm

Comment: @Monte Because you haven't read my full answer ;-) You forgot to execute the first step.

Comment: I did unless I'm doing it wrong? `<label><input type="checkbox" name="drums" onclick='check(this);'><span></span> Drums</label>`, do you have a link to your working code on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/reporter/qhtcdxu2/56/ Btw you have a syntax error in your html. A closing label tag is missing. Maybe that is the reason.